# Error when try dotnet restore multi project solution

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0, .net-core-rc2

I have problem with dotnet restore command
My project has the following structure:
`

```
MyApp
-__gitsubmodule/Lib-bus/project.json (target NetStandart1.6)
Programe.cs
project.json ( target NetCoreApp1.0 )
```

When I run dotnet restore I have:

```
log  : Restoring packages for /MyApp/__gitsubmodule/Lib-bus/project.json...
log  : Restoring packages for /MyApp/project.json...
log  : Lock file has not changed. Skipping lock file write. Path: MyApp/__gitsubmodule/Lib-bus/project.lock.json
log  : MyApp/__gitsubmodule/Lib-bus/project.json
log  : Restore completed in 715ms.
error: Unable to resolve 'Lib-bus (>= 1.0.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0'.
log  : Lock file has not changed. Skipping lock file write. Path: /MyApp/project.lock.json
log  : /MyApp/project.json
log  : Restore failed in 974ms.
Errors in MyApp/project.json
    Unable to resolve 'Lib-bus(>= 1.0.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0'.
```

I think the dotnet can't properly find Lib-bus. I found solution change structure and add global.json but it's is not convenient. Maybe you now the way to set path to Lib-bus. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What do you have in your project.json ? 
Did you referenced Lib-bus with `target: "project"` ?

```
"Lib-bus": {
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "target": "project"
}
```

If you don't want to use the global.json, all packages will be resolved on Nuget if you don't specify `target: "project"`.